# Determine if entity is new without checking @Id

Tags: hibernate, jpa, entity

Is there a way to determine given for example entity class:

```
@Entity
class A {

    String name;

}

boolean method(Object anyEntity) {
     // How can I check here, if this entity is completely new    
}
```

By new, I mean someone invoked `new A()` and possibly even set the name, but was never saved, or persisted.

Normally one could check the id, but I want a solution that does not requires an id, or a getId() method.

Basically, has this entity been persisted in the database, even in detached mode.

`@Version` or `getVersion` is also not a satisfactory solution.

Maybe isDetached || isAttached might work, but I am not sure how to make that call on Hibernates API.

EDIT:

Also clarify, I do not control the entities, so I can not add any fields to them. Solution should try to make use of underlying mechanisms to determine this.

Comment: What if it doesnt have an id field? \@Id can also be set on any field, and doesn't have to be named id. For isntance \@Id String name; would fail here.

Comment: Not sure if this can be achieved in detached mode.

Comment: If you use reference types with `@Id` and `@Version`, why won't `id == null` or `version == null` work?  After all, those fields would have been set only if the entity was ever persisted to the database, which is the only case where you would say that the instance is `new`.

Comment: version is not a requirement. maybe @id is, but it does not have to be auto generated but could be set manually.

Comment: JPA managed entities need to have a mandatory `@Id` field. If identifiers are manually assigned, there is no way to tell if an instance hasn't been persisted yet or is detached, without changing the entity class and without hitting the database. If you can't change entity classes, you can inject fields using aspects. Also, please make sure that you add all necessary information to your question in one go. Right now you seem to be adding information as answers come along and it is beginning to seem like you are doing so just to refute the efforts users are putting in to provide an answer.

Comment: I have already added an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some work and analyzing of Hibernate source code, I believe this is the answer:

```
boolean isNew(T entity) {
        return ((SessionImplementor) session()).getPersistenceContext().getEntry(entity) == null;
}
```

And on another note, getting the id without relying on an implementation can be done as:

```
    boolean hasId(Object entity) {
            return getId(entity) != null;
    }

    Serializable getId(Object entity) {
            ClassMetadata metadata = metadata(entity);
            if ( metadata.hasIdentifierProperty() ) {
                    return metadata.getIdentifier(entity);
            }
            return null;
    }

    ClassMetadata metadata(Object entity) {
            return getRepository().session().getSessionFactory().getClassMetadata(entity.getClass());
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

If any of API method not available then probably we can achieve it using **Listeners:**. This will work across **JPA/Hibernate.**

Like below:

```
@Transient 
private boolean isNew;

@PostPersist
@PostLoad
public void setWhetherNew() {
    isNew = true;
}
```

Comment: There is the method getIdentifier() in SessionImpl, but I am not sure if it's sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

you could use a transient field and use Entity-Listeners to 
set this field.

```
@Transient
private boolean persisted;

@PostLoad
@PostPersist
public void setPersisted() {
   persisted=true;
}
```

you could then use `persisted` to tell whether the entity has been ever persisted or not.

**-- edit --**

`@PostLoad` is required so that already persisted entities loaded from the Database also have `persisted` set to true. Otherwise they would appear as 'new' even though they could be found in the DB.

Comment: Why @PostLoad is required?

Comment: will `persisted`be set to true if you retrieve the entity from database after being persisted?

Comment: If the field is transient, it is not persisted in the database.

Comment: This does not work if someone creates an entity with a new keyword and then sets the id manually to an existing one...

Comment: There is the method getIdentifier() in SessionImpl, but I am not sure if it's sufficient.

Comment: I think @PostPersist is more appropriate as  this call will invoke after the actual database INSERT is executed.

Comment: edited the answer ... @PostLoad will make sure entities loaded from the DB will have set 'persisted' to true.

Comment: @darijan that would mean circumventing hibernate. why would you do that ?

Comment: @AndreR usually it happens so that I have a webserver (I have a website doing something, saving and showing data - right, that's the point?). With, for example, REST I provide data to the user, i.e. a person entity: { id: 1, name: "Peter", lastname; "Crouch" }. Now, the user changes something and saves, it must call again a REST service. The entity that appears on the webserver has id already set (as in my case). Because id is set I merge the changed to the entity for the given id... Want more examples?

Comment: @darijan ok, i was not thinking of merging detached entities or a similar thing when i read your comment. but if you do that you have the responsibility to restore the state of the entity you are about to merge, right ? So in your case when you get back an entities state from a rest call  then it would probably be appropriate to also restore the 'persisted' flag to 'true' by invoking a suitable setter.

Answer (score 0):

you can check if the entity is managed by the PersistenceContext

```
EntityManager.contains(entity)
```

Comment: another way is to check  if the entity is a instance of HibernateProxy

Comment: Yes, maybe. Not sure to do that though. onEvict in DefaultEvictEventListener seems to be removing some stuff from persistence context, including checking HibernateProxy. However, there is an else block as well suggesting there are other cases as well.

Comment: There is the method getIdentifier() in SessionImpl, but I am not sure if it's sufficient.